# how do i use addDays() for opportunity closedate in apex

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce-id

```
opportunity healthopp = new opportunity()
healthopp.closedate=system.today()+1;
```

.
.
 but i need to use addDays(1) instead of system.today()+1 how can i use this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this syntax below:

```
opportunity healthopp = new opportunity(); 
healthopp.closedate = System.today().addDays(1);
```

`addDays(additionalDays)` is a method of the [Date Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm). It adds the specified 
number of additional days to a Date.

Comment: please provide an explanation,imo,  this would count as a mini code dump which is not very useful to the community in general.

Comment: @glls  updated my answer